# What is the maximal number of increasing length-$k$ subsequences?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\rho \in \{1,\dots,r\}^n$ be a string of length $n$ in the alphabet $\{1,\dots,r\}$. A *subsequence* of $\rho$ of length $k$ is the precomposition $\rho\circ \iota$, where $\iota: \{1,\dots,k\} \to \{1,\dots,n\}$ is an injection. Let $O_k(\rho)$ be the number of subsequences of $\rho$ which are strictly increasing. Let $O_k(r,n)$ be the maximum value of $O_k(\rho)$ as $\rho$ ranges over all strings of length $n$ in the alphabet $\{1,\dots,r\}$.

**Questions:**

1. "What is $O_k(r,n)$?" (I think there is no "closed-form" formula, but anything to put it into context would be helpful.)
2. In particular, how close is $O_k(r,n)$ to the trivial upper bound $O_k(r,n) \leq {n \choose k}$?
3. Is it easy or hard to construct examples of $\rho$'s attaining the maximum value $O_k(\rho) = O_k(r,n)$?

I think I could probably find out a lot if I could locate a relevant OEIS sequence, but I'm hindered by the fact that there is more than one parameter here.

Comment: Are you assuming k is much less than r?  A good test case is when n=qr, and rho is the concatenation of r  constant sequences each of length q.  Gerhard "Trying To Size Up Problem" Paseman, 2020.03.05.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I'm interested in the full range of values of $k$, from $k=1$ to $k=r$. Perhaps it is a good idea to look at different regimes separately, though...

Comment: Surely the answer to (3) is that it's hard, because if it were easy then it would be easy to answer (1)?

Comment: When $n\gg r\gg k$, Gerhard Paseman's "test case" yields $O_k(r,n)\sim\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 4):

Generalising Gerhard Paseman's "test case", let $n=qr+s$, where $0\leq s\lt r$, and let 
$$\rho=1^{q+1}2^{q+1} \;\ldots\; s^{q+1}(s+1)^q \;\ldots\; r^q$$ 
be the *equitable* string, in which each of $1,\ldots,s$ occur $q+1$ times and each of $s+1,\ldots,r$ occur $q$ times.
Then, 
$$
O_k(\rho)
=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{s}{j}\binom{r-s}{k-j}(q+1)^j q^{k-j}
=q^k \binom{r-s}{k}{}_2F_1(-k, -s, r-s-k+1; 1 + 1/q).
$$

I'd be inclined to conjecture that this is in fact the value of $O_k(r,n)$.

If the remainder $s$ is zero, then we simply have 
$$\binom{r}{k}\frac{n^k}{r^k}$$
which is easy to analyze.

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting that your conjectured result depends so mildly on $k$ (and uses the same maximizer independent of $k$). Perhaps I shouldn't be surprised, though, since having lots of ordered length-$k$ subsequences is pretty strongly correlated with having lots of ordered length-$l$ subsequences for $k,l >1$.

Comment: The more I consider this, the more I'm convinced that a rigorous proof of the conjecture should be possible.